# Retrieve products price with taxes in openerp report

Tags: python, odoo

I am writing an [Aeroo](http://www.alistek.com/wiki/index.php) report to print OpenERP product labels.

I managed to print product's name, description, image, barcode... but I'm having trouble with prices. I can print product's base price, without taxes:

```
<o.price>
```

but I need to print price with taxes and taxes amount also, how can I achieve this?

EDIT:
this works but must be a better way:

```
<o.list_price * ( 1 + sum([t.amount for t in o.taxes_id]))>
```

and doesn't take into account discounts

thanks,
Lluís

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved creating a module and adding pvp method to product_product which uses tax.compute_all

```
from osv import fields, osv

class product_product(osv.osv):
    _name = "product.product"
    _inherit = "product.product"

    def _pvp(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        """Return calculated PVP with taxes
        """
        res = {}
        tax_obj = self.pool.get('account.tax')
        for product in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
            t = tax_obj.compute_all(cr, uid, product.taxes_id, product.list_price, 1)['total_included']
            res[product.id] = "{0:.2f}".format(t)
        return res

    _columns = {
        'pvp': fields.function(_pvp, type="string", method=True, string="PVP"),  # calculates PVP with taxes
    }

product_product()
```